# Asking if a variable is included in an array though a method in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables, methods

My current code looks a bit like this, but whenever i input one of the variables included in the array I always get a 'no'

```
    def revisar
      var= gets
      a = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird']

      if a.include?(var)
        puts 'yes'
      else
        puts 'no'
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

The `gets` method frequently puts a newline (`"\n"`) at the end of the string. Try this to remove any trailing newline that may be present:

```
var = gets.chomp
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, you simply need to change `gets` to `gets.chomp!`.  Otherwise, a trailing `"\n"` is included in every answer and will never match what's in your array.

```
def revisar
  var= gets.chomp!
  a = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird']

  if a.include?(var)
    puts 'yes'
  else
    puts 'no'
  end
end
```

Comment: No! Do not use #chomp! because `'foo'.chomp! #=> nil`.

Comment: That's not the case here, gets includes a `"\n".`  This is the output: `"foo\n".chomp! => "foo"`

Comment: btw, don't you think it's poor form to downvote someone who is willing to volunteer time to answer a question AND provides a working answer?